# Filename of image in event box

Tags: c++, gtk3

I'm pretty new to GTK3. 
I've created an array of EventBoxes and each of them contains an image. All boxes are linked to the same on_button_pressed method. When the user clicks an image, I'd like to get the file name of the image displayed in the event box. Is there any way this can be done?

Thanks for all the help.

---- EDIT 1 -------------------------

```
Code:

    //In my header file, I've declared:
  class Window : public Gtk::Window{
    //....some other window elements....
    Gtk::EventBox portraits[13];
    Gtk::Image * portraitImage[13];
  };

    //In my .cc file, I've implemented:
   Window::Window(){
    //....creating some window elements ....
     for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
       portraitImage[i] = new Gtk::Image("empty.png");
       portraits[i].signal_button_press_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, 
               &Window::doOnPortraitClicked));
       portraits[i].set_image(*portraitImage[i]);
     }

     //..........some other code for displaying the window..........//
     show_all_children()
   }

   //doOnPortraitClicked method
   bool Window::doOnPortraitClicked(GdkEventButton *  button){
    ??  GValue value = G_VALUE_INIT;
    ??  g_value_init (&value, G_TYPE_STRING);
    ??  g_object_get_property(G_OBJECT(button->get_image()), "file", &value);
    ??  string source = g_value_get_string(&value);

   // How do I retrieve "empty.png" from the EventButton?
   }
```

- The question marks are lines I can't implement

Comment: Please provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). An eventbox is simply a window which handles events (clicks, etc..) for widgets that do not have their own window, but instead draw on the parents window. When you create your array, you presumably create an image on each that you should be able to retrieve when the individual eventbox widget is passed as the first parameter to your click handler (or whatever event you are handling). Without the code, all we can do is guess. (this is also why I prefer C/gtk+2)

Comment: This question lacks information. You can obtain filename from GtkImage (it has such property), or you can pass filename as userdata to your `on_button_pressed`. Or you can create a helper hashtable with image widget pointer as key and filename as value.

Comment: @Alexander Dmitriev, I've made changes to it now. My issue is I don't know how to obtain the Gtk::Image from the EventBox.

Comment: GtkEventBox is subclassed from GtkBin, a container with only one child. In C it has `gtk_bin_get_child` method (I don't know how to call it in C++). Alternatively take a look at [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-multi-item-containers.html.en#sec-helloworld2) which is exactly what are you looking for: passing filenames directly to callback.

Comment: Use [Gtk::Image file property](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Image.html#a1b140df0e81c0411a1a3800618599a5c).